# Error in Select box

Tags: struts2

This is my Assignemployee.jsp file code

```
<s:form action="AssignEmployee" name="myForm">
<s:select name="pname" list="projectlist"  headerKey="0" label="Select a country" />
 <s:submit/>
 </s:form>
```

This is my projectlist.java action file

```
package myPack;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ApplicationAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
public class projectlist extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
HttpServletRequest request;
private List<String> projectlist;
public List<String> getProjectlist() {
return projectlist;
}
public void setProjectlist(List<String> projectlist) {
this.projectlist = projectlist;
}
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
{
this.request = request;
} 
public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest(){
return request;
}
public String getDefaultSearchEngine() {
return "yahoo.com";
}
public projectlist()
{       
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///pmt","root","shree");    
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from addproject");
ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();      
while(res.next()) 
{   
projectlist = new ArrayList<String>();
projectlist.add(res.getString("pname"));
}
ps.close();         
con.close();
} 
catch(Exception e)
{ 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
}
public String execute()throws Exception
{
return SUCCESS;
}
public String display() {
return NONE;
}
}
```

And This is struts.xml

```
<action name="AssignEmployee" class="myPack.projectlist" method="display">
    <result name="success">assignemployee.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When i am running application i get an error like

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/PTMS] threw       exception [tag 'select', field 'list', name 'pname': The requested list key 'projectlist' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]] with root cause
>   tag 'select', field 'list', name 'pname': The requested list key 'projectlist' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

How to solve this error?

Comment: The issue is around the page that *displays* the JSP, not the form submission (unless there's a validation error). Also, indent your code.

Comment: But what was the issue...

Comment: How should I know? I can't see anything regarding the action that displays the JSP with the select box in it. Obviously there's no `projectlist` value. Also, you continually create a new list instead of adding to a single list.

Comment: So how can i fetch the value of projectlist from database...any solution???

Comment: ... The error message indicates you may be accessing the JSP page directly instead of executing the action. You do not provide enough details to help. The DB part itself is fine, except for how you create the list, and access the form the first time.

Comment: Sir, Can you Suggest me code for fetch projectlist from database...

Comment: Why? That's not the problem, other than how you incorrectly instantiate a new list for every row in the result set.

Comment: So What was the solution for that.

Comment: Don't instantiate a new list for every row in the result set.

Comment: I was remove projectlist = new ArrayList<String>(); line and place it before class.forname line. but still it gives error

Comment: Again: that's not related to the error. How are you accessing the form for the **first** time? Through an action? Which action? Show the config for that action.

Comment: Thanks u... Its Working now. And Problem is solved....

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. Project list creation is broken, and
2. The first access to the form is broken.

**1)** You're creating a new list for every row in the result set:

```java
while (res.next()) {   
    projectlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    projectlist.add(res.getString("pname"));
}
```

This should look closer to:

```java
projectlist = new ArrayList<String>();
while (res.next()) {   
    projectlist.add(res.getString("pname"));
}
```

It also appears you never actually *call* this method, although it's difficult to tell since the code is essentially illegible without indentation or any valuable whitespace. *Where* you call it is open to some debate; it could be in the getter itself, a `prepare()` method (and the action would `implement Prepareable`), the `execute()` method, etc.

These kinds of things should likely go into a service, however, as a testability aid.

**2)** I'm not convinced your initial visit to the JSP is being handled correctly. It should:

a) Go through a Struts 2 action,
b) Call the `projectlist` initializer, and
c) Forward to the JSP with the form.

If all those criteria are met, you will not get that error.